# How to get step timing information from SpecFlow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, binding, specflow

[image: SpecFlow]

Above image, you see **red circle** at 40 ms. How am i able to get that timing in step file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Stopwatch class:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

//test codes

stopwatch.Stop();
var elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: I do not want to use Stopwatch. Is that any way we can get that time using SpecFlow object? See, SpecFlow all ready doing it.

Comment: Not exactly, this will include time taken for assert result etc

Comment: @sayse i am just trying to figure out how to take the time what specFlow putting in to report. see this report link http://hamishgraham.net/files/TestResult.html

Answer (score 2):

Rajeem is correct. If you want to time a method, use a `StopWatch`.

The values you are seeing, both in the vs screenshot and your linked report, have values that are generated by the test *runner*s. In the case of the vs screenshot, that information is generated by either Charlie Poole's Nunit adapter https://launchpad.net/nunit-vs-adapter or the built in one for mstest. In both cases, the runner starts the stopwatch, and then starts the test framework, (e.g. Nunit) which calls into SpecFlow. However no interfaces between these parts have any mechanism for passing the timings.

Comment: I know @rajeem_cariazo is correct, and even i have used that Stopwatch in my code to complete the test for now. Wondering if any way i can get that timing using SpecFlow.